# Regex match all websites except for one

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

I am trying to create a regex query to match ALL possible websites excluding one.

```
(https?:\/\/)?+(www)?([^:\/]+\.)?mysite\.[a-zA-Z]{1,3}
```

unfortunately example below will only work for search for ONLY that domain.

I tried adding (!mysite) but that doesn't work. Any ideas?

Playground
https://regex101.com/r/Q4QmVZ/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative lookbehind to exclude your website and do something like this:

```regex
\b(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?<!\bmysite\b)\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}\b
```

Comment: @Alex Careful, that lookbehind will also cancel the `amysite.com`, too.

Comment: Oooh.. That's bad. I tried also adding ^mysite$, that doesn't seem to work to make it exact match

Comment: Good catch, I edited it to be an exact match

Answer (score 1):

With a negative look ahead you can exclude the domain you don't want.

```
\b(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(?!mysite)[\w-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}\b
```

It passes all the tests given but not sure about others.